# how to do unit testing of component with multiple parent routes of ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

Lets say I have a component that access parent route like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    //TODO - FFBZAP-25: far from an ideal solution
    this.sub = this.route.parent.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
        this.siteId = params["siteId"];
        this.loadContents();
        this.loadTypes(this.siteId);
    });
}
```

My issue is that when I run the test I get

> Failed: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

I am not testing the route right now, but I think error should be Because of this line:

- useValue: { parent: { parent: { parent: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'siteId': '156' }]) } } } },

Here is my Unit-test code:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
            HttpModule,
            RouterTestingModule,
            SharedModule,
            BootstrapModalModule
        ],
        declarations: [
            ContentListComponent,
        ],
        providers: [
            SiteService,
            UserService,
            Modal,
            Overlay,
            {
                provide: ActivatedRoute,
                useValue: { parent: { parent: { parent: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'siteId': '156' }]) } } } },
            },
            OverlayRenderer,
            AuthHttp,
            MessageService,
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

    }).compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ContentListComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            siteService = TestBed.get(SiteService);
            userService = TestBed.get(UserService);
            activatedRoute = TestBed.get(ActivatedRoute);

        });
}));
console.log("HEUUUYFYYHSIDDHARTHs", { parent: { parent: { parent: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'siteId': '11' }]) } } } })
it('should have a defined component', () => {
    expect(component).toBeDefined();
});
it('Sholud get content-list', async(() => {

    spyOn(userService, 'getUser')
        .and.returnValue(Observable.of(UpdatedBy));

    spyOn(siteService, 'getSiteContents')
        .and.returnValue(Observable.of(contentList));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    component = new ContentListComponent(activatedRoute, mockModal, mockRouter, siteService, userService);
    component.ngOnInit();


    fixture.whenStable()
        .then(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            return fixture.whenStable();
        })
        .then(() => {
            const totalRows = de.queryAll(By.css('tr'));
            expect(totalRows.length).toEqual(3);
        });
}));
});
```

I have tried to take reference of following links. But I could now get satisfactory result
[How to mock an activatedRoute parent Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789637/how-to-mock-an-activatedroute-parent-route-in-angular2-for-testing-purposes)

[Testing Angular 2 parent route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950552/testing-angular-2-parent-route)

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: @onetwo12  At useValue in the providers block