# how can i create MockActivatedRoute for the parent routes of ActivatedRoute in angular 4 Unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Lets say I have a component that access parent route like this:

```
ngOnInit() {    
this.sub = this.route.parent.parent.parent.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.siteId = params["siteId"];
    this.loadContents();
    this.loadTypes(this.siteId);
});}
```

I m providing fake value for parent route like this:

```
 providers: [
        SiteService,
        UserService,
        Modal,
        Overlay,
        {
            provide: ActivatedRoute,
            useValue: { parent: { parent: { parent: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'siteId': '156' }]) } } } },
        },
        OverlayRenderer,
        AuthHttp,
        MessageService,
    ],
```

it is giving me following error:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined

AT line:

> useValue: { parent: { parent: { parent: { 'params': Observable.from([{ 'siteId': '156' }]) } } } },

Please tell me what it is that i am doing in correct.
i have referenced following link:

[How to mock an activatedRoute parent Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789637/how-to-mock-an-activatedroute-parent-route-in-angular2-for-testing-purposes),
[Testing Angular 2 parent route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950552/testing-angular-2-parent-route)

Comment: try `params: of({ 'siteId': '156' })`