# Angular 4 writing test properly for a parent route subscription

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to write a `unit test` in `Angular 4.3.6`.

I have already looked at the following references:

1. [how can i create MockActivatedRoute for the parent routes of ActivatedRoute in angular 4 Unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789131/how-can-i-create-mockactivatedroute-for-the-parent-routes-of-activatedroute-in-a)
2. [How to mock an activatedRoute parent Route in angular2 for testing purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789637/how-to-mock-an-activatedroute-parent-route-in-angular2-for-testing-purposes)
3. [Testing Angular 2 parent route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40950552/testing-angular-2-parent-route)

Thing is - I don't think (I might be completely wrong) I should mock `ActivatedRoute` in this scenario, for example:

I have a children component which has a `subscribe` to a parent activated route, like that:

```
// children.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.parent.paramMap
    .map(m => m.get("contractId"))
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(contractId => {
      console.log(contractId);
  });
}
```

Now I want to write the following test:

`should call the parent subscription when contractId changes`

I thought something like that:

```
it("should call the parent subscription when contractId changes", fakeAsync(() => {
  // Initializes route with contractId 1000
  router.navigate(["1000", "Parent", "Children"]);

  tick();

  fixture.detectChanges(); // this calls ngOnInit

  // changes the contractId to 2000
  router.navigate(["2000", "Parent", "Children"]);

  tick();

  expect(component.contractId).toBe("2000");
}));
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramMap' of null

I published a plunker for that: https://plnkr.co/edit/2SXzvSDe3OiwvvRJYXfN?p=preview

Note that in the plunker I wrote two tests. The first one is running just fine, so the router is working.

How can I watch for changes in the route in the unit test and why is `parent` null?

**EDIT:**

I updated my plunker with the mocked `ActivatedRoute` based on [ActivatedRouteStub](https://angular.io/guide/testing#create-an-observable-test-double). Then now I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'paramMap' of undefined

That is probably because the **stub** does not define parent, consequently it's undefined.

I could define a `parent` property in the mock, but would this be correct?

Comment: if you will mock `ActivatedRoute` then you have to pass or create all possible value `ActivatedRoute` uses in your test.

Comment: As @AniruddhaDas said. Basic params: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356084/how-to-unit-test-a-component-that-depends-on-parameters-from-activatedroute. Parent params: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40789637/how-to-mock-an-activatedroute-parent-route-in-angular2-for-testing-purposes

Comment: I did this already, but my subscription does not get called, I thought it was because of the mock